# How to get down scaled photos with fixed width?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I use the [fotoapparat.io library](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) to shoot my photos. Since I do not need full resolution of those 12 or 15 mega pixels I would like to scale that image down to "768 x H" whereas H is my heigth dependinmg on cameras aspect ratio; usually 4:3 so 576 pixels.

Neither invoking:

```
 photoResult.toBitmap(
                    new Function1<Resolution, Resolution>() {
                        @Override
                        public Resolution invoke(Resolution resolution) {
                            float scale = (float) 768 / resolution.width;
                            return scaled(scale).invoke(resolution);
                        }
                    }
            )
```

nor scaling:

```
    photoResult.toBitmap(
        new Function1<Resolution, Resolution>() {
            @Override
            public Resolution invoke(Resolution resolution) {
                int height = 768;
                int width = 576;
                Resolution r = new Resolution(width, height);
                return scaled(1.0F).invoke(r);
            }
        }
    )
```

helped for me. For second example, when using fixed 1.0F as scaling factor it distorted the image. Or 4/3 as scaling factor the image had good ratio but it was then scaled down to 576 x 432 pixels.

**How can I scale down images to a fixed width without distroting the aspect ratios of different cameras?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have java code to rescale bitmap. I used this to scale my image down to "600 x H".

```html
private Bitmap rescaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        float constant = 600.0f / bitmap.getWidth();
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * constant),
                (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * constant), true);
    }
```

Comment: I dont want post processing. I want to do it in the fotoapparat.io toBitmap(), it lowers also crashes on older devices with low memory when creating BitmapPhoto objects (raw files approx 30 MB on full resolution)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **TakeInfo** answer, you should store images as small as it's possible, but you can resize images anytime by changing an ImageView params

```
ImageView.getLayoutParams().width = your_width;
ImageView.getLayoutParams().height = your_height;
```

Here's sample of ImageView widget, which is working for me

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: No an answer to my question. I dont want post processing